# Display HTML document in Activity

Tags: android, textview, android-webview

I am parsing an RSS feed using SAX to display a list of the title of the latest posts.

When I click the title, it opens the browser, showing that URL.

However I want to display the article, including the HTML styling and images in a new activity.
I can get the article part by parsing the variable 'encoded'

[Link.](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20feed%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http://feeds.feedburner.com/jamesaltucher%3Fformat%3Djson%22)

It is pure HTML. It also contains `<img src='...'>` tags. 
What would be the best way to display this in an activity?

`TextView` can display HTML, but I don't think it displays images.
`Webview` can show local HTML, but in this case, it will be dynamic.

Is there any way to display an HTML document in an Activity, including styling and images?

Comment: A `WebView` can load remote content perfectly fine, not just 'local HTML'.

Comment: so how can I dynamically pass the HMTL data to a webview?
Is there any direct way? Instead of saving it to a db or to a file?

Comment: Your starting point would be the [`WebView` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). In particular, look at the `loadData(...)` and `loadUrl(...)` methods for respectively loading local and remote content.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). There's more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) too.

Comment: so how can I dynamically pass the HMTL data to a webview? Is there any direct way? Instead of saving it to a db or to a file?